# Trig inequality $|\tan x-\tan y|\leq \frac{1}{\cos^2 c}|x-y|$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, inequality, absolute-value

Let $0<c<\frac{\pi}{2}$. Show that the following holds for all $x,y\in [-c,c]$:

$$|\tan x-\tan y|\leq \frac{1}{\cos^2 c}|x-y|$$

I've thought about applying [this lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871581/trig-identity-proof-of-tanx-tany/871622) but I haven't been able to figure out so far how to exactly do that in the above case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the mean value theorem and the fact that $\tan'=\frac1{\cos^2}$.

Comment: Thank you, so now I have that $|\tan x-\tan y|=|x-y||\tan' \xi|$ for some $\xi$ but how do I continue from here?

Comment: $$\lvert\tan'\xi\rvert=\left\lvert\frac1{\cos^2\xi}\right\rvert=\frac1{\cos^2\xi}.$$

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my problem: How do I make the connection to the given $c$?

Comment: Since $\frac1{\cos^2}$ is increasing on $\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$, $$\frac1{\cos^2\xi}\leqslant\frac1{\cos^2c}.$$

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\cos$ decreases on $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ and by the Lagrange's theorem there is $\theta\in(0,1),$ for which:
$$|\tan{x}-\tan{y}|=\frac{|x-y|}{\cos^2\theta c}\leq\frac{|x-y|}{\cos^2 c}$$